# Minimize edge count in directed graph, allowing auxiliary nodes

Tags: graphs, optimization

Suppose I have a directed acyclic graph $G$. I want to find a graph $H$ containing the nodes of $G$ (and potentially more) which minimizes the number of edges in the graph, without changing the reachability between the nodes of $G$. That is, if a path from $s$ to $t$ exists in $G$ a path from $s$ to $t$ must also exist in $H$, and conversely if no such path exists in $G$ it may also not exist in $H$.

Is this a known problem that has a name? My Google-fu is failing me. Does it have efficient solutions or approximations?

As an example, the graph on the left has 7 edges while the graph on the right only has 6 by introducing a new node. Both graphs have exactly the same reachability matrix, ignoring the introduced auxiliary node.

[image: graph]

Comment: A very similar problem to this is called *edge concentration*, and was shown to already be NP-hard for the bipartite graph case by Xuemin Lin in *On the computational complexity of edge concentration*. The difference between this and the problem above is that I allow multiple levels of auxiliary nodes, whereas in their problem each auxiliary node may be at most one edge away from existing nodes as pointed out by @John L.

Comment: Another related article is *Confluent Layered Drawings* by David Eppstein et. al, which if I'm not mistaken also contributes on StackExchange. So perhaps he'll stumble upon this question.